# How to remove leading and trailing spaces/underscores in variable names when using PROC IMPORT?

Tags: sas

I have some variable names like "  A and B   " with 3 leading and 3 trailing spaces in the excel file. When using PROC IMPORT, under validvarname = v7, all spaces are read as underscores.
Is there an easy way so that the variable names are read as "A_and_B"?

I have a x64 SAS with x86 Excel. To import, File Server is enabled and DBMS = EXCELCS is used in PROC IMPORT.

I have tried validvarname = v7, = any, validmemname as well.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to rename them after importing by using `proc datasets`. The easiest way is to construct the variable rename statements with sql and `dictionary.columns`.

Suppose you have a table that looks like this, where your columns have leading spaces.

```
    a and b|     c and d         
1          | 4
2          | 5
3          | 6
```

If you use `validvarname=any`, you will read these in as-is. If we do that, we can construct code that removes any leading or trailing spaces. For example:

```
rename '    a and b'n = a_and_b
       '    c and d'n = c_and_d
;
```

We'll use SQL to create this code for us, then save it to a space-separated macro variable that we can pass into a `rename` statement of `proc datasets`. All we need to do is tell SQL to create a string with the format:

`'old name1'n=new_name1 'old name2'n=new_name2 'old name3'n=new_name3 ...`

This can be done with the following function:

`cat(nliteral(name), '=', tranwrd(strip(name), ' ', '_'))`

This says to create a name literal around the variable `name`, append an equals sign, then append the same variable name that has no leading or trailing blanks, and has any spaces within it converted to underscores.

```
options validvarname=any;

proc import 
    file = "have.xlsx"
    out  = want
    dbms = xlsx
    replace;
quit;

proc sql noprint;
    select cat(nliteral(name), '=', tranwrd(strip(name), ' ', '_'))
    into :rename_vars separated by ' '
    from dictionary.columns
    where libname='WORK' AND memname='WANT'
    ;
quit;

proc datasets lib=work nolist;
    modify want;
    rename &rename_vars;
quit;
```

```
NOTE: Renaming variable '    a and b'n to a_and_b.
NOTE: Renaming variable '    c and d'n to c_and_d.
```

Answer (score 0):

You have no control over how PROC IMPORT (or the XLSX engine) generates the names.  But it should not be hard to convert the names after the fact.

Say you created the dataset HAVE from your Excel sheet.  First get the list of names and then generate the new names and put the old=new pairs into a macro variable and use that in a RENAME statement (or RENAME= dataset option).

```
proc contents data=HAVE out=contents noprint;
run;

proc sql noprint;
  select catx('=',nliteral(name),nliteral(newname))
    into :renames separated by ' '
  from (select name
             ,translate(strip(translate(trim(name),' _','_ ')),' _','_ ') as newname
        from contents
       )
  where name ne newname
  ;
quit;
%if &sqlobs %then %do;
proc datasets lib=WORK nolist;
  modify have;
  rename &renames;
  run;
quit;
%end;
```